# Joomla Sp Page Builder Off-Canvas Menu

Tags: joomla3.0

I have questions about off-canvas menu for mobile phone and tablet. My website is burak.expandingcode.com

Mobile side:

- When I navigate the website using my mobile phone (Iphone7) in portrait and landscape mode in off-canvas menu, I want to add a logo under the flags.
  (mobileportrait.png, mobilelandscape.png)

Tablet side:

- When I navigate the website using my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S) in landscape mode, I want to add off-canvas menu instead of mega menu like portrait mode. (tabletlandscape.jpg)

Could you please help me about these subjects?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem:

You can add a new menu item with your logo at the beginning of the menu, and then hide it on desktop using `@media` and css selector `first-child`